# if/else in pl SQL loop

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, if-statement

I am attempting to update the units in stock with `IF.. ELSE` conditions and statements, but I'm getting an error when trying to run it:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:
    if
```

Code below, I am running it on a loop to spit out all the data until it runs out:

```
DECLARE

--Declare cursor
 CURSOR part_cur
 IS 
 SELECT PARTNUMBER, PARTDESC, ITEMCLASS, UNITSONHAND, UNITSONHAND
 FROM PART
 ORDER BY UPPER(PARTNUMBER);

--Declare variables
 v_PartNumber PART.PARTNUMBER%TYPE;
 v_PartDesc PART.PARTDESC%TYPE;
 v_ItemClass PART.ITEMCLASS%TYPE;
 v_UnitsOnHand PART.UNITSONHAND%TYPE;
 v_nUnitsOnHand PART.UNITSONHAND%TYPE;

BEGIN
 OPEN part_cur;
 LOOP

--Initialise variables
  FETCH part_cur INTO v_PartNumber, v_PartDesc, v_ItemClass, v_UnitsOnHand, v_nUnitsOnHand;
        EXIT WHEN part_cur%NOTFOUND;

--Perform Calculations
    IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND <20 THEN v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 5;
ELSE IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND <100 THEN v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 10;
ELSE IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND >=100 THEN v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 25;
END IF;

--Format for output

--Output results
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Part ' || UPPER(v_PartNumber) || ' - ' || INITCAP(v_PartDesc) || ' of item class ' || UPPER(v_ItemClass) || ' had a total of ' || v_UnitsOnHand || ' units on hand, 
        and now has ' || v_nUnitsOnHand || ' units on hand after the database was updated.
        ');
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE part_cur;
END;
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `IF` statement currently looks like this:

```
IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND <20 THEN
    v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 5;
ELSE
    IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND <100 THEN
        v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 10;
    ELSE
        IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND >=100 THEN
            v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 25;
        END IF;
```

so it's missing two `END IF`s. So when Oracle sees the `END LOOP`, it complains, because it expected an `END IF` instead.

To fix this, just replace both of your `ELSE IF`s with `ELSIF`, which is a special keyword for exactly this purpose:

```
IF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND <20 THEN
    v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 5;
ELSIF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND <100 THEN
    v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 10;
ELSIF ITEMCLASS = 'AO' AND UNITSONHAND >=100 THEN
    v_nUnitsOnHand := UNITSONHAND + 25;
END IF;
```

Comment: Oh cheers thanks, I didn't realise how deep my `ELSE.. IF` statements were going.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
FOR record_var in part_cur
LOOP
   {...statements...}
END LOOP;
```

After that you can write:

```
record_var.v_PartNumber, etc
```

for accessing these fields.